# Python dictionary: How to check for of a string in a tuple key in order assign the associated value

Tags: python, python-2.7

A Pythonewbie, I am attempting to create a function that will check a string against a dictionary words for months and pull the value for the month. Essentially, I am not sure how iterate over tuples used as keys in a dictionary. See below:

```
import re

def main():
    '''A script to convert a date cluster in word form to date in number form'''

    the_clipbrd = '''November 30, 2014     Logo mugs ordered Tom
    March 4, 2014 A bag of tricks Fred'''

    the_result = grind_wordgorian(the_clipbrd)

def grind_wordgorian(the_lines):
    '''Process date formats that have months in English clusters 
    separated by periods, dashs, or slashes'''

    month_dict = {
    ('January','Jan.','Jan'):'01',
    ('February','Feb.','Feb'):'02',
    ('March','Mar.','Mar'):'03',
    ('April','Apr.','Apr'):'04',
    ('May'):'05',
    ('June','Jun.','Jun'):'06',
    ('July','Jul.','Jul'):'07',
    ('August','Aug.','Aug'):'08',
    ('September','Sept.','Sept', 'Sep'):'09',
    ('October','Oct.','Oct'):'10',
    ('November','Nov.','Nov'):'11',
    ('December','Dec.','Dec'):'12'
    }

    for the_line in the_lines.splitlines():

        ## Find a word cluster  which might have month word followed by a date and a year.
        some_dates = re.findall(r'\s?([\w.]{3,9})[-\./ ](\d{1,2}),? ?(\d{0,4})(\s?)', the_line)

    ## go through everything found
        for the_date_cluster in some_dates:
            ## Check to see if there is a month in word form
            the_month = the_date_cluster[0]
            ## Hey this works!
            print 'The ' + the_month

            ## Check to see if the first cluster is a month in word form 
            ## return the correct month in number form .

            ## Wait, how do I do that?

## Ensures main is called if it the main script
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer in two parts, first a direct answer to your specific question, then what I think might be an easier approach.

**1. Iterating over the keys**

You can get a list of all the keys in a dict by doing `my_dict.keys()`. In your example, that would yield a list of tuples. You would need to iterate over that list and compare the found string against each tuple:

```
key_list = month_dict.keys()
month_number = None
for key_tuple in key_list:
    if the_month in key_tuple:
        month_number = month_dict[key_tuple]
        break
```

Now `month_number` has your number in it. But this is probably not what I'd do.

**2. Restructuring your month dict**

Instead, I would split out your tuples, so that each element is its own key in the dict. Then getting the number for a given month string just becomes a matter of indexing into the dict, like this:

```
month_number = month_dict[the_month]
```

Your dict would look more like this:

```
month_dict = {"Jan": "01",
              "January": "01",
              "Feb": "02",
              ...
              "December": "12"}
```

Note that if you get a string that isn't in your month dict, trying to index into the dict with it will throw an exception (see the [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) documentation for more info on how to approach this scenario).

You might also check out the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and [calendar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#module-calendar) modules, as they might offer some help with whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: Your second option looks like the way to go, but raises the question for me. When would using a tuple in a key be efficient? What purpose would it hold if you can’t easily iterate over it?

Comment: It would be rare, but you might do it if your keys needed to be combinations of various items, with each potential combination hashing to something different. But then you'd have to worry about the order of the elements in the tuples and it'd get kind of funky. I'm not saying there's never a use case, it's just not one you would necessarily run into often. And if you did do it, you would want the COMBINATION of the elements to be what matters, not the individual elements (i.e. you shouldn't normally be iterating over each individual key).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go is to keep the dictionary simple with only the shortest common prefix of each item in the tuple keys:

```
month_dict = {"Jan": "01",
              "Feb": "02",
              ...
              "Dec": "12"}
```

and then retrieve the number by truncating the string you want to convert to the corresponding number

```
print month_dict[the_month[0:3]]
```